# Modular Arithmetic - Find the Square Root

Tags: modular-arithmetic

In my math notes it shows this example:

> *Example*: Compute the square root of $3 \pmod{143}$.
> We have $143=11\cdot 13$.
> (Then he jumps to this:)
> $$
> \sqrt{3}\equiv \pm 5 \pmod{11} 
> $$
> $$
> \sqrt{3}\equiv \pm 4 \pmod{13}.
> $$
> Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, we can calculate the four square roots as $82,
> 126, 17$ and $61$.

The lecturer never makes anything clear even though it is our first encounter with modular arithmetic. I don't know were the $4$ or the $5$ come from or the $\sqrt{3}$. Can anyone explain to me how he got the solutions above?

And also how does he use this information in conjunction with the *Chinese Remainder Theorem* in order to arrive at the square roots? I would really appreciate if anyone could help me out here.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are actually several different concepts here, so I'll try to address all of them.  I'll get to the modular arithmetic in just a moment, but first a review:

**SQUARE ROOTS**

We should know that 25 has two square roots in ordinary arithmetic: 5 and -5.

**MODULAR ARITHMETIC SQUARE ROOTS**

*IF the square root exists*, there are 2 of them modulo a prime.  To continue our example, 25 has the two square roots 5 and -5.

We can check this:

$$(-5)^2 = 25 \equiv 3\bmod 11$$
$$(5)^2 = 25 \equiv 3\bmod 11$$

To find the square roots sometimes takes a bit of trial and error.  Often you have to go through each value $v$ and square it (to get $v^2$) to check if it's equivalent to $n \bmod p$, where $n$ is the number whose square root you want to find.

**MULTIPLE PRIMES**

Again, if a square root exists, there are two square roots modulo *each* prime.  So if we are using multiple primes, there can be more square roots.  For example, with two primes, there are 2 square roots modulo the first prime and two square roots modulo the second prime.  This gives us $2 \cdot 2 = 4$ square roots.

*In general, if we can find a square root modulo each prime, there are a total of $2^n$ square roots modulo $n$ primes.*

**RETURNING TO YOUR EXAMPLE**

We can first calculate 3 modulo 11 and 13:

$$3 \equiv 3 (\bmod 11)$$
$$3 \equiv 3 (\bmod 13)$$

So, modulo 11, we are looking to find a number that, when squared, is *equivalent* to 3.  If we find one, we know that there will be another.  So we check the numbers:  $1^2 \equiv 1$, $2^2 \equiv 4$, $3^2 \equiv 9, \dots$ and find that

$$5^2 = 25 \equiv 3 (\bmod 11)$$

...so we know that there will also be another square root modulo 11.  Continuing on our quest, we check

$$6^2 = 36 \equiv 3 (\bmod 11)$$

...so we've found the square roots modulo 11.  We then continue this modulo 13 to find that:

$$4^2 = 16 \equiv 3 (\bmod 13)$$
$$9^2 = 81 \equiv 3 (\bmod 13)$$

So we know that our square root is either 5 or 6 modulo 11, and either 4 or 9 modulo 13.  This gives us 4 possibilities.  We can then find that:

$$82 \equiv 5 (\bmod 11), 82 \equiv 4 (\bmod 13)$$
$$126 \equiv 5 (\bmod 11), 126 \equiv 9 (\bmod 13)$$
$$17 \equiv 6 (\bmod 11), 17 \equiv 4 (\bmod 13)$$
$$61 \equiv 6 (\bmod 11), 61 \equiv 9 (\bmod 13)$$

Comment: Modulo a prime, there will be at most two square roots, because unique factorization holds in $\Bbb F_p[x]$ (so that $x^2 - a$ has at most two roots for $a\in\Bbb F_p$). Modulo a composite, there can be more. Your mistake comes because $5\equiv -6\pmod {11}$, and $6\equiv-5\pmod{11}$, so you really only found two unique square roots.

Comment: @Stahl:  You're right.  I will fix my answer.

Comment: Also, $5$ is not two different values modulo $11$, and $5\not\equiv 6\pmod{11}$: as I said in my above comment, $-5\equiv 6\pmod{11}$. $-5\equiv 6\pmod{11}$ doesn't mean that there are two different values of 6; it means we have two ways of writing the same thing, just like $.99\ldots = 1$ as real numbers. When we write $a\equiv b\pmod n$, we're really saying that when we work in $\Bbb Z/(n)$, $a + n\Bbb Z = b + n\Bbb Z$ (this is one way of defining modular arithmetic). They represent the same element, or value, in the system we're working with, they're simply written differently.

Comment: @MattGroff Hi I am learning about the same topic discussed in this post. Can you please explain why we know that our square root is either 5 or 6 modulo 11, and either 4 or 9 modulo 13.  Also where do we get the 4 possibilities from. E.g. where do we get 82,126,17 and 61.

Comment: @Jed:  Perhaps the easiest way to see what we're trying to explain is to think of inverses.  We can state the additive inverse of $x$ as $y$, and then we have $x \equiv (-1)y$.  But if we square $x$, and rewrite this in terms of the inverse $y$, we have $(x)^2 \equiv ((-1)y)^2$, which equals $(-1)^2 y^2$, which, of course, is $y^2$.  So we have just shown that the squares of $x$ and its inverse $y$ are the same value.  So if we can find any square root, we can call it $x$.  Then its inverse, $y$, when squared, is the same value.  If we find one square root, its inverse is also a square root.

Comment: Perhaps “This gives us 2⋅2=4 primes” should say  “This gives us 2⋅2=4 roots”.  Also fix “We can firs calculate”

Answer (score 3):

Consider:
    x≡√3(mod11);
    x²≡3(mod11);
    x²≡3+22(mod11);
    x²≡25(mod11);
    x≡±5(mod11);
So, x=+-5
You can do something similar mod 13.

```
Let x≡5(mod11);
x≡-5(mod11);
x≡4(mod13);
x≡-4(mod13)
```

Then use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to find the four values of x (mod 143)

Answer (score 2):

suppose you want to find (x)^(1/2) mod p(prime) then simply calculate (x)^((p+1)/4) mod p.
as in your case x=3 and p=11,
3^((11+1)/4)=27= 5 mod 11. similarly -5 will be a root.

Comment: This is incomplete. $x^{(p+1)/4}$ is only a square root mod $p$ of $x$ if $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ and hence is only applicable in the case $p=11$. This does not work with $p=13$

Answer (score 1):

Working modulo $11$, using numbers from $0$ to $10$, which ones have the property that their squares are of the form $11k+3$ ? Similarly, modulo $13$, using numbers from $0$ to $12$, which ones have the property that their squares are of the form $13k+3$ ?