# Is X a square in $\Bbb Z$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am learning about number theory and cryptography. I have a style of question that I have not seen before and I do not have any examples to go off of.

The question is:

Is 50 a square in $\Bbb Z^x_{71}$? Find the principal
square root of it, if the answer is positive.

Is this question solved similarly to [Modular Arithmetic - Find the Square Root](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633160/modular-arithmetic-find-the-square-root)?

Since 71 is prime it cannot be broken down to any number but itself and 1, how do you solve for squares?

Comment: $50+71=121$, a square.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Is it really that simple?

Comment: In this case, yes. In general, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to consider the quadratic residues modulo $71$.  So this means computing $1^2,\ 2^2, \ 3^2 \ ... 70^2$ modulo $71$.  The set of numbers that this forms is the quadratic residue mod $71$.  When doing so, you will find that $50$ is in this residue class.

An easy way to think of it is as follows.  You are not finding square roots, you are finding square numbers and in turn what the roots of these square numbers are.

Check this link out for more information. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue

Comment: "An easy way to think of it is as follows. You are not finding square roots, you are finding square numbers and in turn what the roots of these square numbers are." This line made it click for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

For $x^2 < 71, 50$ is not a square.
So now we take $x^2 = 71 + 50$ and it turns out $11^2 = 121 = 50(\mod 71)$

Comment: This also was very helpful, thank you.