# EC Point calculation

Tags: elliptic-curves

Following the Guide to [Elliptic Curve Cryptography](http://diamond.boisestate.edu/~liljanab/MATH308/GuideToECC.pdf), it provides the following elliptic curve on $E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ with $p=29$ on page 80:

$E: y^2 = x^3 + 4x + 20$

Page 81 provides a list of the points on the curve. For $x=2$ it includes the points $(2,6)$ and $(2,23)$. Let's do the calculation:

\begin{align*}
x &= 2\\
y &= \pm \sqrt{x^3 + 4x + 20} \bmod 29\\
y &= \pm \sqrt{2^3 + 4 \times 2 + 20} \bmod 29\\
y &= \pm \sqrt{8 + 8 + 20} \bmod 29\\
y &= \pm \sqrt{36} \bmod 29\\
y &= \pm 6 \bmod 29\\
y_1 &= +6 \bmod 29 = 6\\
y_2 &= -6 \bmod 29 = 23\\
\end{align*}

Thus, we have the points $(2,6)$ and $(2,23)$.

Doing the same calculation for $x=3$ fails:

\begin{align*}
x &= 3\\
y &= \pm \sqrt{x^3 + 4x + 20} \bmod 29\\
y &= \pm \sqrt{3^3 + 4 \times 3 + 20} \bmod 29\\
y &= \pm \sqrt{27 + 12 + 20} \bmod 29\\
y &= \pm \sqrt{59} \bmod 29\\
y &= \pm 7,68 \bmod 29
\end{align*}

This fails, since it is not an integer.

If I do the mod before the sqrt, I get the correct result for $x=3$:

$$\pm\sqrt{59 \bmod 29} = \pm\sqrt{1} = 1$$

If I do the same for $x=2$, then it fails again:

$$\pm\sqrt{36 \bmod 29} = \pm\sqrt{7} = \pm 2,64$$

Conclusion: Doing mod after sqrt breaks $x=3$, doing mod before sqrt breaks $x=2$.

Question: What do I miss respectively what am i doing wrong? Is there a special sqrt-operation for mod?

[EDIT 1]: Using Wolfram Alpha, I get the correct numbers.

- $x=2$: [$y^2 = 36 \bmod 29$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%5E2+%3D+36+mod+29) $\Rightarrow y = 6$ and $y=23  \Rightarrow (2,6)$ and $(2,23)$
- $x=3$: [$y^2 = 59 \bmod 29$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%5E2+%3D+59+mod+29) $\Rightarrow y = 1$ and $y=28 \Rightarrow (3,1)$ and $(3,28)$

But how does it work?

[EDIT 2]: Just found [Cipolla's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipolla%27s_algorithm), which solves $x^2\equiv n \pmod{p}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is arithmetic in finite fields. You have to take modular square roots. Here the examples with Pari/GP

```
? x=Mod(36,29) 
%1 = Mod(7, 29) 
? x^(1/2) 
%2 = Mod(6, 29)
? x=Mod(59,29) 
%3 = Mod(1, 29) 
? x^(1/2) 
%4 = Mod(1, 29)
```

So yes, there is *there a special sqrt-operation for mod?*
See e.g. [Modular square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_square_root) or the [Tonelli-Shanks algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm). A Q/A on this site is [Modular Arithmetic - Find the Square Root](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633160/modular-arithmetic-find-the-square-root#633174).