# How to find square root mod N by knowing N factorization

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

Suppose we know $p$ and $q$ two prime number, is there a way to find $x$ to satisfy this equation for $x$:
given $a$ and $n$ where $n =pq$
find $x$ such that
$x^2=a \bmod n$.

Comment: There are some other questions / answers that address this, but none of them are very satisfactory, IMO like https://math.stackexchange.com/a/633174/746312 but maybe it's good enough for you? Basically (assuming $p\neq q$) solve for each prime individually and then use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to combine them.

Comment: thank you sir for your precious time.

Comment: For square roots modulo a (large) prime, there is the [Tonelli-Shanks algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm).

Comment: sir, thank you for your precious time I appreciate that.